# Odoo Sending mail is not working

Tags: python, email, odoo

This is my Python code. While clicking on the button it gives error. Help me to resolve this issue.

```py
    def send_quot_mail(self, cr, uid, ids,vals, context=None):
        cur_obj=self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context)
        stage = self.pool.get('crm.case.stage').browse(cr, uid, cur_obj.stage_id.id,context=context)
        no_of_days=stage.days_to_move
        end_date =datetime.datetime.now()+ relativedelta(days=no_of_days)
        print end_date
        mail_date=end_date.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
        vals.update({'qout_mail_date':mail_date})

        mail_ids=[]
        mail_pool = self.pool.get('mail.mail')
        template_pool = self.pool.get('email.template')

        template_id = self.pool.get('ir.model.data').get_object_reference(cr, uid,'custom_crm', 'email_template_crm_lead')[1]
        mail_id = template_pool.send_mail(cr, uid, template_id, cur_obj.partner_id.id, context=context)
        template_obj=self.pool.get('email.template').browse(cr, uid, template_id, context=context)
        message_to_sent=template_obj.body_html
        cur_obj=self.pool.get('res.users').browse(cr, uid, cur_obj.partner_id.id, context=context)

        mail_pool.write(cr, uid, mail_id, {'email_to':cur_obj.partner_id.email,'body_html':message_to_sent}, context=context)
        mail_ids.append(mail_id)
        if mail_ids:
            mail_pool.send(cr, uid, mail_ids, context=context)

        return super(crm_lead, self).write(cr, uid, ids,vals, context=None)
```

This is my Mail Template XML Code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>
     <record id="email_template_crm_lead" model="email.template">
            <field name="name">CRM Lead Opportunity Stage</field>
            <field name="email_from">noreply@localhost</field>
            <field name="subject">CRM Lead Opportunity Stage</field>
            <field name="email_to"></field>
            <field name="partner_to"></field>
            <field name="model_id" ref="custom_crm.model_crm_lead"/>
            <field name="body_html">
                <![CDATA[
                    <div style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; color: rgb(34, 34, 34); background-color: #FFF; ">
                        <p></p>
                    </div>
                ]]>
            </field>
        </record>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

While I click the button I get error

> MissingError One of the documents you are trying to access has been
>   deleted, please try again after refreshing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it right by removing the following line from the code. I am able to send mails now.

> cur_obj=self.pool.get('res.users').browse(cr, uid,
>   cur_obj.partner_id.id, context=context)

now I am not getting the error

> MissingError One of the documents you are trying to access has been
>   deleted, please try again after refreshing.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to get the wrong template by reference:

```py
template_id = self.pool.get('ir.model.data').get_object_reference(cr, uid,'custom_crm', 'model_crm_lead')[1]
```

Your record is defined by id (external id, xml id, ...) `email_template_crm_lead`. So you have to get the template for this id:

```py
template_id = self.pool.get('ir.model.data').get_object_reference(cr, uid,'custom_crm', 'email_template_crm_lead')[1]
```

Edit:

```py
cur_obj=self.pool.get('res.users').browse(cr, uid, cur_obj.partner_id.id, context=context)
```

seems to be wrong, because you're trying to find a user (res.users) with an id of a partner (res.partner). That can maybe produce a match (e.g. id 3 for admin) but can also end up in your reported MissingError.

Actually you're using `cur_obj.partner_id.id` quite often. Where is `cur_obj` coming from???

Comment: But then I getting the same error even after changing the xml id.. @CZoellner

Comment: I edited the question with my full python code. But then I am getting same error.